# ssh which directory to put files in

Tags: ssh, documentation

I am extremely new to ssh.

I have logged in through ssh, but i dont know which directories should i put files in and can anybody recommend me a tutorial which will give me a quick overview of it. Video tutorial will be preferred.

Comment: What files? We need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess here is that you're a Windows or Mac user and you've just started using ssh to connect to a Linux server.

If that guess is correct....

First, realize that ssh is just the tool which allows you to have a remote command line session on this other server. Once you're connected, ssh is transparent and mostly irrelevant to what you're doing there.

Next, now that ssh is out of the picture, you're really asking about what you do with files and directories on a Linux server. The specifics of that will vary depending on the version of Linux you're using and the shell you're using (the shell is the program used to accept and process the commands you type).

You can find the version of Linux by typing `lsb_release -a`. The output will likely include "Fedora", "Red Hat", "Debian", or "Ubuntu". Google for tutorials about that linux version.

You can find which shell you're using by typing `echo $SHELL`. The output will most likely say "/bin/bash" or something else with 'bash' in it. Google for bash tutorials.

Finally, the location of files and directories can also be dependent on what they're used for. If you're working with files to be served by the Apache web server, they'll need to be put in a location which is defined by your Apache web server. Again, google for tutorials specific to the software you're using.

Comment: Nice answer . I'm looking for a detail one about Linux ssh,